# Запятая в конструкциях типа "делай что хочешь"

Tags: пунктуация

В выражениях типа "делай что хочешь" запятая не ставится, так как "что хочешь" здесь в значении "что угодно". Подходит ли под данное правило предложение
"Сиди, отдыхай, смотри (,) что нравится"?

Буду очень благодарна, если кто-нибудь сможет объяснить этот момент.

Comment: Объяснение отсутствия запятой у вас странное. Чем "что угодно" отличается от "что хочешь"?

Comment: Прошу прощения, это я взяла ответ справочной службы Грамоты: ‘Если слова все что хочешь используются в значении "что угодно, абсолютно все", то верная пунктуация такая: Им можно все что хочешь рассказать, и они поверят.’

Comment: Или ещё: В рекламе встретили предложение "Я покупаю что хочу". Без запятой. Однозначно трактовать найденные правила не смог, поэтому прошу помощи профессионалов - нужна ли здесь запятая перед "что"?
Ответьте со ссылкой на правило, пожалуйста.
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Запятая не требуется, так как слова «что хочу» употребляются в значении «что угодно, всё».

Answer (score 2):

Я не профессионал, но могу поделиться своим видением. Если речь идет о конкретных желаниях, то запятые ставятся.

> Вопрос № 291122
>   Добрый день! Подскажите, как правильно расставить знаки препинания в предложении "Если бы люди делали все что хотели вовремя они были бы более счастливы."? Нужна ли в данном случае запятая перед "что"? И почему?
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   Корректно: Если бы люди делали все, что хотели, вовремя, они были бы более счастливы.

А если в обобщенном смысле (абсолютно все можно делать), то запятая не ставится:

> Вопрос № 292181
>   В предложении Им можно все, что хочешь рассказать, и они поверят. Нужна ли запятая после слова "хочешь?" Буду признательна за ответ.
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   Если слова все что хочешь используются в значении "что угодно, абсолютно все", то верная пунктуация такая: Им можно все что хочешь рассказать, и они поверят.

Оборот "смотри что нравится" в вашей фразе "Сиди, отдыхай, смотри что нравится" нестандартен, тяготеет к разговорной речи, поэтому трудно дать в отношении него однозначный ответ. Мне думается, он здесь по сути является эквивалентом "смотри что хочешь" (абсолютно все можно смотреть), поэтому запятая не нужна.

"Я покупаю что хочу" не требует запятой, так как говорит о возможности покупать абсолютно все. Сравните: "Я покупаю, что хочу, а не то, что мне навязали".

Answer (score 1):

**Сиди, отдыхай, смотри (то), что нравится.**

Ситуация вполне конкретная (без обобщения): выбери программу, которая тебе нравится.

Сравнить: **Будешь дома один, вот тогда и смотри что хочешь** (что угодно).

Вообще говоря, в устойчивых выражениях обычно применяется оборот ***что хочешь*** со значением "что угодно", глагол ***нравится*** для этого сочетания не очень подходит.

Comment: По смыслу скорее "смотри **все** (,) что нравится", чем "смотри **то**, что нравится".

Comment: Да, пожалуй, но запятая ставится и в этом случае.

Comment: "Запятая ставится и в этом случае". Даже если слово "все" опущено? В этом-то я и не уверен, остается поверить Вам на слово.

Comment: При прямом значении это придаточное: выбери, что нравится. При переносном (обобщенном) значении  это разрешение смотреть всё без ограничений.